# Property values to select tag in struts 1.x

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I have list of items in property file which needs to be converted to dropdown list in my jsp without hitting action class

The format of my list of items in property file is as below

```
   dropDownList  = itemkey1,itemValue1|itemKey2,item2Value|item3Key,item3Value
```

I want that `dropDownList` key value to populate as drop down list in jsp

How can I do that using Struts 1.x tags. I know how to do using getting from action class and populating. Just wondering if there is any way which we can to using tags itself.